# DataTables: trouble formatting to stripe rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

Problem: I have a basic web app running to take from the user an ID number and a date, the result of the submission of said info returns a dataset from my DB. the data is properly formatted and displayed into a nice html table. I am using DataTables 1.10.2 (http://www.datatables.net/) to handle the formatting of my table of the page. Within the datatables .css file I CAN change the colors and hover over colors and fonts, I can get the column widths to change as I need, but I CAN NOT get the rows to appear with the 'stripe' presentation. This is my html file (a piece of it not everything) for my web page:

```
<!--- jQuery --->
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--- DataTables --->
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> -->

<!--- DataTables CSS --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/test.css">
<!--- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> --->

<script> 
<!--- tells the browser to use DataTablkes to style the html tables --->
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#table_id').dataTable();
});

...

<p>Enter the Advertiser ID and the Date to start at that you wish to report for.</p>

<p>Keep the date in the format YYYY-Mon-DD</p>

<div>
<label>Date :</label>
<!-- <input id="dateSub" type="text" value="YYYY-Mon-DT"> -->
<input id="dateSub" type="text" value="2014-Sep-05">
<label>Advertiser Id :</label>
<input id="adSub" type="text" value="351155">
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>

<table id="table_id" class="stripe" width="auto" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Hour</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This code works fine, as is...that is without trying to add into the script that identifies the table_id to over ride the default features of DataTables, ie: display compact, hover, stripe...only the default 'display' works.

I want to be able to set the display of the DataTable as a striped table via class='stripe' but am unable to do so by adding the 'stripe' keyword into the class=" " portion of the HTML table. Whereas this is how the the examples of the stripe table are shown to work on the documentation that I have read through so far. Also above you will see i commented out the original datatables.css file and am using a 'test.css' file...it is an exact copy of the original datatables.css file that comes with the DataTables1.10.2 package. Also all other files associated with the DataTables package have been left 'AS-ARE' after copying up to my web server.

This issue aside everything else works as one would expect, but this would be a really nice feature to have work. And the issue may be something that will keep me from progressing further, and is very annoying.

Added the full HTML source document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>:: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx ::</title>

<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../images/icons/small_icon.jpg">

<style>
body {background-color:#C8C8C8;}
<!--- p {color: grey;} ---> 
</style>

</head>


<!--- loading in our scripts --->

<!--- JQuery --->
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--- DataTables --->
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<!--- Datatables CSS --->
<!--- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/test.css">


<script> 

$(document).ready( function () { $('#table_id').DataTable(); });

$(document).ready( function () {

////////
$('#button1').click(function(){
console.log('asdfasdf')
var date = $("#dateSub").val();
var adid = $("#adSub").val();
var dataString="adid="+adid+"&"+"qdate="+date;
console.log(date+" "+adid)

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(data){
var jsonArr = $.parseJSON(data)
var body=$("#table_id").find('tbody')
console.log('returned')
body.empty()
for (var i=0;i<jsonArr.length;i++){
body.append('<tr><td>'+jsonArr[i].hour+'</td><td>'+jsonArr[i].count+'</td></tr>');
}
}
})
})
/////////
})
</script>
```

This is everything that I left out of the above code snippet, perhaps this will help narrow down the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that dataTables adds the classes of 'even' and 'odd' to every row in the table. Have you tried applying css rules to them?

something like this seems like it should work to me:

```
table tbody tr.even{
    color:#444;
}
```

So, for example, when my table is generated, the html ends up looking something like this.

```
<table class="dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="table_info">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td class=" limitWidth">Dangerously</td>
            <td class=" limitWidth">Johnny</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">08/19/2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td>2</td>
            <td class=" limitWidth" title="Jingleheimerschmidt">Jingleheimerschmidt</td>
            <td class=" limitWidth">John</td>
            <td class="sorting_1">06/12/2014</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: I messed up. This needs a colon in the css, not an equals sign.

Comment: thanks for that quick reply! I have tried this like such; but to no success:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    
    ...

    <style>
    body {background-color:#C8C8C8;}
    table tbody tr.even{
    color=#444;
    }
    <!--- p {color: grey;} --->
    </style>

    </head>.....

or should I have put this code into the datatables.css file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the generated html end up looking something like the example I  just added to my answer? Make sure that the classes are added to the rows as in my example.

Comment: And to answer the question you just asked, it shouldn't matter if it's in the datatables.css file, I think, but I guess it may be being overridden. You can try putting a !important on the color, to check, but I don't think that's the 'correct' solution.

Comment: Also, I incorrectly said to use a '=' in the css. Try it with a ':' instead.

Comment: S. Buda, when my table is displayed on the screen the underlying html is no different from what i submitted ABOVE. I am using ajax to change what is displayed for the table. I will add the whole html source.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with data tables quite a bit nothing stood out in your code to me - so I created a quick fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nrq49ort/1/)
Nothing is really wrong with your code, but the grey background on the odd rows is very subtle - so maybe it doesn't show on your screen? I set the following css - not very pretty but at least it's hard to miss ;)

```
.odd {
      background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

When i add this to either the in-line css and the datatables css upon first sight of the table with nothing in it I see the first row is red, after I submit the data in the form to the web app running in the background and the table is populated all formating of the table, colors the stripeing ,etc disappear...not sure what is going on here. Could ity be that i am running the form data through ajax and this is then changing the way the datatable is showing up? I don't think this should be the case if I put the css rules in the css file and in-line css rules...

Comment: How do you add the new rows to your table? Can you show some code?

Comment: Ah - I see you've already added how you add the new rows -and it makes it more clear what's going on. Take a look here: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html
You need to actually add your new row to the DataTable object and then call draw() - just modifying the DOM doesn't add the proper styles and will break not only formatting but also paging

Comment: hmm reading through now and trying to figure out where I should add this into my js...Up above in the complete script snippet that i provided, would i want this type of code to go in this peice of the js: "$(document).ready( function () { $('#table_id').DataTable(); });" or in the part of the js that includes the ajax bit?

Comment: You want to change your success callback function. To something like this (note: not tested!) 
var tbl = $("#table_id").DataTable();
and then inside your loop: 
t.row.add([jsonArr[i].hour, jsonArr[i].hour]);
and finally you need to make sure you re-draw your table (outside your for loop!)
Are you sure you really want to empty the entire table however and not just add the new rows to what you've already fetched before? You could cut down on the load by just returning the newly added row and add just that to your table (so, no for loop, less parsing, ..)

Comment: Birgit, thanks for your help so far, unfortunately I have yet to be able to progress any further with these efforts atm because of a new problem that has arisen that is preventing me from testing my code.see my new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774468/error-dbx-91773-rtcg-compilation-failed